# Spring boot Microservices logging with Graylog

Tags: spring-boot, graylog2

I want to use Graylog/RabbitMQ for logging with my spring boot microservices. As per my understanding I have to send my logs to RabbitMQ and have to integrate it with Graylog. I want to know the workflow and how to implement it like how to send the logs to RabbitMQ, do I need to use any other logging framework.

Comment: Do you want either of these two? Or send logs to RabbitMQ first then consume from there? Latter should be used if you multiple consumers, graylog being one of them.

Comment: @SukhpalSingh ...Can i send logs to graylog directly? I read some blogs and i find out that i have to use  any message broker like Kafka or RabbitMQ and integrate graylog with message broker. It's fine for me if i can send logs directly to the graylog from my Spring boot App. Graylog is the only one consumer. Can u explain the workflow.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Logback appender to send logs from spring-boot app. Add following dependency to your `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>de.siegmar</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-gelf</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Then you need to add a logback configuration file to your classpath.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml" />
    <appender name="GELF" class="de.siegmar.logbackgelf.GelfUdpAppender">
        <graylogHost>localhost</graylogHost>
        <graylogPort>12201</graylogPort>
        <maxChunkSize>508</maxChunkSize>
        <useCompression>true</useCompression>
        <layout class="de.siegmar.logbackgelf.GelfLayout">
            <originHost>localhost</originHost>
            <includeRawMessage>false</includeRawMessage>
            <includeMarker>true</includeMarker>
            <includeMdcData>true</includeMdcData>
            <includeCallerData>false</includeCallerData>
            <includeRootCauseData>false</includeRootCauseData>
            <includeLevelName>false</includeLevelName>
            <shortPatternLayout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
                <pattern>%m%nopex</pattern>
            </shortPatternLayout>
            <fullPatternLayout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
                <pattern>%m</pattern>
            </fullPatternLayout>
            <staticField>app_name:backend</staticField>
            <staticField>os_arch:${os.arch}</staticField>
            <staticField>os_name:${os.name}</staticField>
            <staticField>os_version:${os.version}</staticField>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <root level="debug">
        <appender-ref ref="GELF" />
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

For more information: [logback-gelf](https://github.com/osiegmar/logback-gelf)